# Repeat Find in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I make a macro start at the beginning of a doc and repeat it until the end of the word doc and not have to manually repeat the macro all the time?

I read that I should use DO UNTIL/WHILE LOOP but I have no idea how to do it, since I created the macro with the "RECORD MACRO" function of Word.

I managed to repeat a couple of times, copying and pasting the relevant parts of the code. Of course, it only repeats for as many times I pasted it.

This is what Word recorded (it works fine for 1 line, finds a tab character and moves the line 5.5 cm left).

```
Sub aaTabs()
'
' aaTabs Macro
'
'
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^t"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .SpaceAfterAuto = False
        .FirstLineIndent = CentimetersToPoints(-5.5)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, it only works if the tab is the first character, not sure if this is what you want or not

```
Sub MoveTab()
Dim para As Paragraph
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
 If para.Range.Characters(1) = Chr(9) Then
    para.Format.FirstLineIndent = CentimetersToPoints(-5.5)
 End If
Next para
End Sub
```